# Replace subscribe block to before footer via XML

Tags: layout, blocks, xml, rwd

I'd like to move up the subscribe block up one block on the rwd theme.

Default:

```
<reference name="footer">
        <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="footer.newsletter" as="newsletter" after="footer_store_language" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Tried xml:

```
<reference name="root">
        <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="footer.newsletter" as="newsletter" output="toHtml" before="footer" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

This does outputs the newsletter subscribe box to root, but **after** the footer block. How do I change this so it will output **before** my footer?

(reason: This block is usually nested with the footer block. I want to make newsletter full width while keeping footer boxed, therefore I have to unnest both)

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look into the root template. There is no `$this->getChildHtml(<NO PARAM>)` therefore you can not just add a block and magento will take care of it.

You have to change the root block to insert your newsletter (and I would swear your block is still in footer, anything else doesn't make sense - at least in my mind)